# Summing null columns with columns with values

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to just confirm that, if any column is having some null values and another column has values what will be the answer when we add them,
will it be NULL, 0 or values

I have tried the MongoDB code, which shows me a result of three types one result with NULL, one with 0 and one with showing values

```
db.EMP.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$ENAME",total:{$sum:{$add:["$SAL","$COMM"]}}}})
```

this one above shows the values 0

```
db.EMP.aggregate([{$project:{ENAME:1 , total:{$add:["$SAL","$COMM"]}}}])
```

this one above show values NULL

Data For MongoDB:

[image: Data For MongoDB]

My result 1:

[image: My result 1]

My result 2:

[image: My result 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/):

> ignores the non-numeric values and returns the sum of the numeric
>   values

while [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) expects:

> any valid expression as long as they resolve to either all numbers or
>   to numbers and a date

So if you want to handle missing values or nulls you should use only `$sum`.

If you just want to sum those fields within each document individually you can do use `$project`:

```
db.EMP.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      total: {
        $sum: [
          "$SAL",
          "$COMM"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you need to group documents and sum across multiple documents you can first `$sum` SAL and COMM separately in the `$group` stage, and then `$sum` them within each document using `$project`:

```
db.EMP.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$ENAME",
      SAL: {
        $sum: "$SAL"
      },
      COMM: {
        $sum: "$COMM"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      total: {
        $sum: [
          "$SAL",
          "$COMM"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```